# Angular $modal and ui-router not playing nicely

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've got an app which launches a modal window using $modal.open from a specific route state. If I click my submit button on the modal, it happily goes away, does the processing it's supposed to do, then calls $modalInstance.close() and closes and everything's great.

Similarly, if I click outside the modal window, or hit escape, the modal window closes as expected and all is well.

However, I've got a close button, which calls $modalInstance.close(). If I click on this, the window closes as expected, but I lose the state of my app. ie, when the modal is opened, the url is .../appName/search/basic, which corresponds to a state of appName.searchBasic, after the modal closes the url is just .../appName, which corresponds to a state of appName.

The state doesn't change until after $modalInstance.close() is called, so I can't see why it's behaving differently when I hit the submit button rather than the close button.

Comment: can you please paste your code here? see if you can provide link with close button to your desired path so that when user clicks on close you provide route  .../appName/search/basic.

Comment: Thanks @Sudarshan - going through the code to paste it in, I discovered the problem. The close button is actually a link, and it has href="#" defined. Getting rid of the # solved the problem :-)

Comment: please vote for the answer thanks is meaning full but if you vote that will inspire people like me to ans future ?s. all the best.happy coding:-) if my answer is correct then shall i write it in answer box.?? you vote me if my suggestion helped you .